# Output correct "datetime" <time> attribute (Umbraco/Razor)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, umbraco

I'm looking to output a timestamp of when content was published within Umbraco, in the correct format required by the HTML5 `<time>` element.

For example:

```
<time datetime="2012-02-28T20:00+00:00" pubdate>February 28, 2012</time>
```

Is there a way to achieve this within Umbraco or with Razor? I know with PHP there's a particular "W3C" way of outputting timestamps: http://goo.gl/sEFsh.

More info on correct formatting of this element can be found here: http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best option for this might be to use the global "UpdateDate" like this:

```
<time datetime="@Model.UpdateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTH:mmzzz")" pubdate>
    @Model.UpdateDate.ToLongDateString()
</time>
```

Seems to output the desired format and the date published rather than the current date. Can anyone see any issues with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

How about this in razor:

```
@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz")
```

This does not generate any output for seconds and milliseconds as in your example.

Comment: Thanks! That produces the exact date output I'm after `2012-02-29T15:55+00:00`.

Last part is to have it output the date published rather than the current date?

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think the format string you may be looking for is "o", like this (in razor):

```
@{
var now = DateTime.Now;
}
<time datetime="@now.ToString("o")" pubdate>@now.ToLongDateString()</time>
```

Produces this for me:

```
<time datetime="2012-02-28T11:41:50.3697628-05:00" pubdate>Tuesday, February 28, 2012</time>
```

Comment: That's great - I get the same output! I'm now looking to remove the unnecessary digits from the end of the time strong and have it output the date published rather than the current date.

Comment: In addition, this code seems to work within a .cshtml Scripting File, but not within a page template. Does it need to be formatted slightly differently for this?

Comment: You can add the pubdate to the model or the ViewBag or however you want to get it to your view code. You can also use more precise formatting like this: @Model.PubDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz") - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for all the formatting possibilities. As for the page template thing, I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting, `@Model.PubDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTH:mmzzz")` doesn't output anything for me, might that mean the published date isn't available to that page? `@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz")` from @marapet below outputs correctly, just the wrong date!

Thanks for the MSDN link, I'll give that a read.

Comment: Where is your PubDate variable stored? In the controller action, set it like this: ViewBag.PubDate = [logic]; Then in the .cshtml code, call it like this: @ViewBag.PubDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz")

Answer (score 1):

Use .ToString("s")

```
<time datetime="@Model.UpdateDate.ToString("s")">...</time>
```

The output will generate: "2013-02-15T21:15:07" and pass html validation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I usually just use this code in cshtml

```
@yourDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")T00:00+00:00
```

Comment: In your example where would `yourDate` refer to? I'm looking to output the date published.

Comment: its a variable holding a reference to whatever date you wan't to print. You're mentioning something about "the date published" but that's an implementation detail that is irrelevant to your question.